# Get the ViewController name from id and call the particular view method

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

i want to get the **viewcontroller** name  from **id** and using id call that class method which is fetch from id.

**Code :-**

```
UIViewController *view = (UIViewController*)self.objCurentCallLocation;
[view LocationCalledAndReturned];
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You mean you want to check the actual *class* of the view controller?

Comment: Yes, I want the class through which I can call method of that class.

Comment: no i want to convert to id to class. class name is not static its dynamic

Comment: id objCurentCallLocation; 
Now, objCurentCallLocation is any kind of class, link NSObject, UIView and UIVIewController and I want to call method of that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand from your code and description, there is an easier way to do what you want. You could use *protocol*, or check whether controller responds to selector.

```
if ([self.objCurentCallLocation respondsToSelector:@selector(LocationCalledAndReturned)]) {
    [self.objCurentCallLocation performSelector:@selector(LocationCalledAndReturned)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the class of the view controller by:

```
Class c = [view class];
```

You can test it to make sure it's the one you want by:

```
if ([view isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]]) {
    // now you know it's safe you can cast it
    [(MyViewController *)view LocationCalledAndReturned];
}
```

You can get the class name by:

```
NSString *name = NSStringFromClass(c);
```